# What's the deal with gitlab (and github?) security?

Tags: security, github, privacy, gitlab

I just wanted to raise an issue (ie. report a bug) in some software package hosted on gitlab. I have a github account, but not a gitlab one.

Whenever I log in from a new device (github), I need to "authorize" the new device.
Now, I tried "logging in" on gitlab using the offered github account/password authentication.

I got the usual "confirm this email address" thing.

I did that.

Then it wanted my phone number!

At this point I gave up. Do they also need my social security number, date of birth and passport number? Maybe my mother's maiden name?

What's the need for all this two-factor-authentication level security?

Comment: There's nothing in your question even related to Linux or Unix...

Comment: I suppose not. But pretty much all OSS I come across (which is virtually all software for Unix/Linux) is hosted on github. And I didn't find a particularly good other area to ask in. I've been making bug reports and submitting fixes for  *three decades* and have never had to give anyone my real name, credit card and phone number until now. So, leaving asside the ranting, I was genuinely puzzled. My curiosity has, however, been satisfied. :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a private website's policies

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as it's commonly said in security.stackexchange, *[Two factor authentication is worth it when one form of authentication is not enough or when it makes sense to have an added layer of Security.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24652/two-factor-authentication-when-is-it-worth-it)*

what if someone find outs your password, they could delete your repos permanently without a way of getting it back, because git* assumes you are using 2fa for security so that if a person gets your password, they would also need the other part of the "puzzle". If you feel so bothered by that, you can always turn that off, but git* will nag you to turn it on for security purposes, you can use alternative methods of 2fa such as a yubikey that satisfies the "requirement" of 2fa

Comment: Fair enough. If they delete my free open source repos (who *does* that?) -- I'll re-upload them. I know what 2FA is -- I use it for banking. Why am I paranoid? Well, I once started getting spam phone calls (you know, from India, "This is MicroSoft support. Your system is infected with a virus. You must give me remote access to your machine, so that I can fix it... etc.") -- so many that I cancelled my phone contract and got a new number.